# Compare dates between two dates at specific positions

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Given the following sample records within the table: **MY_DATES**, using Oracle SQL and/or PL/SQL, I need to always take the first DATE_REGISTERED in this table, i.e. 26/10/2019 and then advance to the third DATE_REGISTERED record/value, i.e. 2/02/2020 and check if the difference is greater than 13 weeks, between them, i.e.

```
select to_date('2/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy') - to_date('26/10/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') a from dual

Table Name: MY_DATES

NM  DATE_REGISTERED
--- ---------------
A1  26/10/2019
A1  2/11/2019
A1  2/02/2020
A1  9/02/2020
A1  16/02/2020
A1  23/02/2020
A1  1/03/2020
A1  8/03/2020
```

The end result for this exercise is to return distinct NM value data where this criteria is satisfied.

Comment: Stating the desired output would be helpful. Explaining the logic is fine, but it by itself doesn't tell us what result you need. Also, what role does NM play in this? I assume you are looking at the data partitioned by NM, but I don't see anything about that in your question.

Comment: @mathguy I have uodated my question based on the end result sought.

Comment: Another question became apparent as I was solving the problem. What if a NM has only two rows in the table, and the dates are more than 13 weeks apart? They don't even have **three** dates, so from your description it would appear that they should not be included in the input. Is that the correct problem statement though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an efficient solution using the MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause, introduced in Oracle version 12.1.

The WITH clause simulates the input data (it's not part of the solution - remove it and reference your actual table and column names in the main query).

The solution partitions by NM and orders by DT, then it looks for three consecutive rows where the third date is more than 13 weeks after the first. As soon as it finds one such occurrence, it fills the "match pattern" with all the remaining rows in the partition, essentially throwing them away - since we only care about a single match.

Note the two NM I added. BB does have dates that are more than 13 weeks apart, but not within three consecutive dates. CC has two consecutive dates that are already more than 13 weeks apart; CC is not in the output because there aren't three distinct dates to begin with. (Note - that's how I read the requirement; if instead what was needed is "consecutive dates more than 13 weeks apart should also count", that can be addressed easily - but that's not the wording in the poster's question.)

```
with
  my_dates (nm, date_registered) as (
    select 'A1', to_date('26/10/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'A1', to_date( '2/11/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'A1', to_date( '2/02/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'A1', to_date( '9/02/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'A1', to_date('16/02/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'A1', to_date('23/02/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'A1', to_date( '1/03/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'A1', to_date( '8/03/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'BB', to_date( '2/03/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'BB', to_date('14/03/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'BB', to_date('18/03/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'BB', to_date('10/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'BB', to_date( '3/04/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'CC', to_date('15/08 2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual union all
    select 'CC', to_date('15/02/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual
  )
-- end of sample data (for testing only); query begins below this comment
select nm
from   my_dates
match_recognize(
  partition by nm
  order     by date_registered
  pattern   ( a b c x* )
  define    c as date_registered > a.date_registered + 91
);



NM
----
A1
```

** **EDIT** **

Re-reading the problem, it seems that only the **first three dates** should ever be considered (not **any three consecutive** dates).

That makes the problem simpler. And the solution can be modified easily - the only change needed is to the `pattern` clause, it should become:

```
pattern ( ^ a b c )
```

This anchors the search for three rows at the beginning of the partition. The other rows aren't inspected.

Comment: That is correct, I will always be looking at the top three dates (if they exist for each NM) and then want to see if there is a difference of 13 weeks. Based on this @mathguy, I will now need to use pattern (^ a b c) for this - correct?

Comment: @tonyf - yes, correct. If you are not familiar with `match_recognize` but you are with regular expressions: `match_recognize` works on the same principle, but it is looking for "rows" instead of "characters". `a, b, c` are symbolic names for rows that satisfy the `define` conditions. (So, `a` and `b` can be **any** rows.) `^` is the anchor at the beginning of the partition.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to Oracle's MATCH_RECOGNIZE clause.

Answer (score 1):

That seems strange.  I am thinking `lead()` and `lag)`.  If you want the `nm` values that meet the condition:

```
select md.*
from (select md.*,
             lead(date_registered, 2) over (partition by nm order by date_registered) as next_dr_2,
             lag(date_registered) over (partition by nm order by date_registered) as prev_dr
      from my_dates md
     ) md
where prev_dr is null and
      next_dr_2 > date_registered + interval '91' day;
```

Comment: That is correct - I need to return distinct NM value where this criteria is satisfied.

Comment: Great - thanks. The thing is now is that I need to feed the all the MY_DATES records , i.e. nm/date_registered  recs as a group by nm and order by date_registered asc and then run your code over them.